# c++ random cout statement causes program to crash inside overloaded '=' operator

Tags: c++

I had to turn this program in for homework and it's already been graded, got an 80.  I'm going back and cleaning up some of the code.  At the bottom of my code is the function to overload `= operator`.  For some reason, the `cout` statement that I've commented out, causes my program to crash, however, when I remove the //s the program runs fine...

Anyone have any ideas why this would be?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Poly
{
    private:
        int order; //order of the polynomial
        int * coeff;//pointer to array of coeff on the heap

    public:
        Poly();
        Poly(int Order);
        Poly(int Order, int * Coeff);
        ~Poly(){/*cout << "Deconstructor\n";*/};
        Poly(const Poly &rhs);

        //accessors &  mutators
        void set();
        void set(int * Coeff, int Order);
        void Print2();
        void PtrReset();
        int getorder(){return order;};
        int * get()const{return coeff;};

        //Overloaded Operators
        Poly operator+(const Poly &rhs);
        Poly operator-(const Poly &rhs);
        Poly operator*(const int scale);
        Poly operator=(const Poly &rhs);
        Poly operator*(const Poly &rhs);
        const int& operator[](int I)const;
        int& operator[](int I);
        bool operator==(const Poly &rhs);
        int operator( )(int X);
        friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & Out, const Poly &rhs);
        friend istream & operator >>(istream & In, Poly &rhs);
};

int main()
{
    int coeff1[ ] =  {-19,1,-12,3,1};
    int coeff2[ ] = {-19,1,-6,0,0,7,0,-1};

    bool flag;

    Poly P1(4, coeff1);
    Poly P2(7, coeff2);
    Poly P3;
    P3 = P1 + P2;
    cout << "P1 + P2: " << P3;
    P3 = P2 - P1;
    cout << "P2 - P1: " << P3;
    P3 = P1 * 10;
    cout << "P1 * 10: " << P3;
    P3 = P1 * P2;
    cout << "P1 * P2: " << P3;
    flag = (P2 == P2);
    cout << "P2 and P2 are ";
    if (flag)
        cout << "Equal\n";
    else
        cout << "Not Equal\n";
    flag = (P1 == P2);
    cout << "P1 and P2 are ";
    if (flag)
        cout << "Equal\n";
    else
        cout << "Not Equal\n";
    cout << "P1(4) = " << P1(4) << endl;
    cout << "P1: ";
    cout << P1;
    cout << "P2: ";
    cout << P2;
    P1[3] = P2[5];
    cout << "P1(after P1[3] = P2[5]): " << P1;
    P1[3] = P2[4];
    cout << "P1(after P1[3] = P2[4]): " << P1;

    return 0;
}

Poly::Poly()
{
    coeff = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    order = 0;
    *coeff = 0;
    //cout << "Default Constructor\n";
}

Poly::Poly(int Order)
{
    order = Order;
    coeff = new int[order+1];
    for(int i(0); i <= order; i++)
        coeff[i] = 0;
}

Poly::Poly(int Order, int * Coeff)
{
    order = Order;
    coeff = Coeff;
}

Poly::Poly(const Poly &rhs)
{
    order = rhs.order;
    int *temp;
    temp = (int *) malloc((rhs.order + 1) * sizeof(int));
    coeff = (int *) malloc((order + 1) * sizeof(int));
    temp = rhs.coeff;
    for(int i(0); i <= order; i++)
    {
        *coeff = *temp;
        coeff++;
        temp++;
    }
    PtrReset();
}


void Poly::set()
{
    coeff = (int *) malloc((order + 1) * sizeof(int));
    if(coeff == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Error allocating memory!\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    cout << "Begin entering with the non x value, then x^1 coefficient, x^2, etc:\n";
    for(int i(0); i <= order; i++)
    {
        cout << (i+1) << ". ";
        cin >> * coeff;
        coeff++;
    }   
    PtrReset();
}

void Poly::set(int * Coeff, int Order)
{
    order = Order;
    for(int i(0); i <= order; i++)
    {
        *coeff = *Coeff;
        coeff++;
        Coeff++;
    }
    PtrReset();
}


void Poly::Print2()
{
    for(int i(0); i <= order; i++)
    {
        cout << * coeff << " ";
        coeff++;
    }
    cout << endl;
    PtrReset();
}

void Poly::PtrReset()
{
    for(int i(0); i <= order; i++)
        coeff--;
}

Poly Poly::operator+(const Poly &rhs)
{
    int neworder;
    int * newpointer;
    int * temp;
    temp = rhs.coeff;
    if(order >= rhs.order)
    {
        neworder = order;
        newpointer = (int *) malloc((neworder+1) * sizeof(int));
        for(int i(0); i <= rhs.order; i++)
        {
            *newpointer = *coeff + *temp;
            newpointer++;
            coeff++;
            temp++;
        }
        for(int i(0); i < (order - rhs.order); i++)
        {
            *newpointer = *coeff;
            newpointer++;
            coeff++;
        }       
    }
    else
    {
        neworder = rhs.order;
        newpointer = (int *) malloc((neworder+1) * sizeof(int));
        for(int i(0); i <= order; i++)
        {
            *newpointer = *coeff + *temp;
            newpointer++;
            coeff++;
            temp++;
        }
        for(int i(0); i < (rhs.order - order); i++)
        {
            *newpointer = *temp;
            newpointer++;
            temp++;
        }       
    }
    PtrReset();
    for(int i(0); i <= neworder; i++)
        newpointer--;

    return Poly(neworder, newpointer);
}

Poly Poly::operator-(const Poly &rhs)
{
    int neworder;
    int * newpointer;
    int * temp;
    temp = rhs.coeff;
    if(order >= rhs.order)
    {
        neworder = order;
        newpointer = (int *) malloc((neworder+1) * sizeof(int));
        for(int i(0); i <= rhs.order; i++)
        {
            *newpointer = *coeff - *temp;
            newpointer++;
            coeff++;
            temp++;
        }
        for(int i(0); i < (order - rhs.order); i++)
        {
            *newpointer = *coeff;
            newpointer++;
            coeff++;
        }       
    }
    else
    {
        neworder = rhs.order;
        newpointer = (int *) malloc((neworder+1) * sizeof(int));
        for(int i(0); i <= order; i++)
        {
            *newpointer = *coeff - *temp;
            newpointer++;
            coeff++;
            temp++;
        }
        for(int i(0); i < (rhs.order - order); i++)
        {
            *newpointer = 0 - *temp;
            newpointer++;
            temp++;
        }       
    }
    PtrReset();
    for(int i(0); i <= neworder; i++)
        newpointer--;

    return Poly(neworder, newpointer);
}

Poly Poly::operator*(const int scale)
{
    int neworder = order;
    int * temp = new int[order+1];

    for(int i(0); i <= order; i++)
        temp[i] = scale * coeff[i];

    return Poly(neworder, temp);
}
Poly Poly::operator*(const Poly &rhs)
{
    int neworder = order + rhs.order;
    int * newcoeff;
    int * temp;
    temp = rhs.coeff;
    newcoeff = (int *) malloc((neworder + 1) * sizeof(int));
    for(int i(0); i <= neworder; i++)
    {
        *newcoeff = 0;
        newcoeff++;
    }
    for(int i(0); i <= neworder; i++)
        newcoeff--;

    for(int i(0); i <= order; i++)
    {
        for(int j(0); j <= rhs.order; j++)
        {
            *newcoeff += (*coeff * *temp);
            newcoeff++;
            temp++;
        }
        coeff++;
        for(int j(0); j < rhs.order; j++)
            newcoeff--;
        for(int j(0); j <= rhs.order; j++)
            temp--;
    }
    for(int i(0); i <= (neworder - rhs.order); i++)
        newcoeff--;
    PtrReset();

    return Poly(neworder, newcoeff);
}
bool Poly::operator==(const Poly &rhs)
{
    bool test = true;
    int count = 0;
    while(test && (count <= order))
    {
        if(order != rhs.order)
            test = false;
        else if(coeff[count] != rhs.coeff[count])
            test = false;
        count++;
    }


    return test;
}

int Poly::operator()(int X)
{
    int * temp;
    int * temp2;
    temp = (int *) malloc((order + 1) * sizeof(int));
    temp2 = temp;
    for(int i(0); i < order; i++)
        coeff++;
    for(int i(0); i <= order; i++)
    {
        *temp = *coeff;
        temp++;
        coeff--;
    }
    coeff++;
    for(int i(0); i < order; i++)
        temp--;
    for(int i(0); i < order; i++)
    {
        *temp += (X * *temp2);
        temp++;
        *temp2++;
    }
    return *temp2;
}

ostream &operator <<(ostream& out, const Poly &source)
{
    for(int i(source.order); i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if(i == 1)
        {
            if(i == source.order)
                if(source.coeff[i] == 1)
                    out << "X";
                else if(source.coeff[i] == -1)
                    out << "-X";
                else
                    out << source.coeff[i] << "X";
            else if(source.coeff[i] == 1)
                out << " + " << "X";
            else if(source.coeff[i] == -1)
                out << " - " << "X";
            else if(source.coeff[i] > 0)
                out << " + " << source.coeff[i] << "X";
            else if(source.coeff[i] < 0)
                out << " - " << abs(source.coeff[i]) << "X";
        }

        else if(i > 1)
        {   
            if(i == source.order)
                if(source.coeff[i] == 1)
                    out << "X^" << i;
                else if(source.coeff[i] == -1)
                    out << "-X^" << i;
                else
                    out << source.coeff[i] << "X^" << i;
            else if(source.coeff[i] == 1)
                out << " + " << "X^" << i;
            else if(source.coeff[i] == -1)
                out << " - " << "X^" << i;
            else if(source.coeff[i] > 1)
                out << " + " << source.coeff[i] << "X^" << i;
            else if(source.coeff[i] < -1)
                out << " - " << abs(source.coeff[i]) << "X^" << i;
        }
        else
        {
            if(source.coeff[i] > 0)
                out << " + " << source.coeff[i];
            else if(source.coeff[i] < 0)
                out << " - " << abs(source.coeff[i]);
        }
    }
    out << endl;

    return out;
} 
int& Poly::operator[](int I)
{
    if(I > (order + 1) || I < 0)
    {
        cout << "Request to access outside Poly boundaries!" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    return coeff[I];
}
const int& Poly::operator[](int I) const
{
    if(I > (order + 1) || I < 0)
    {
        cout << "Request to access outside Poly boundaries!" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    return coeff[I];
}
Poly Poly::operator=(const Poly &rhs)
{
    order = rhs.order;

    //cout << "new order = " << rhs.order << endl;  ******HERE*******

    for(int i(0); i <= rhs.order; i++)
        coeff[i] = rhs.coeff[i];
    return Poly(order, coeff);
}
```

Comment: #include <iostream> and 'using namespace std' should be at the top of my code.

Comment: please include the error message.  Does it segfault? Does it print before it crashes? Have you compiled with `-g` and run it with `valgrind` or `gdb` to see what line the crash actually occurs on?

Comment: You mix new and malloc and never delete them. Operator= should return a non-const reference to *this. Why do you return a temporary object?

Comment: Too much code. Can't you come up with a smaller version that still exhibits the problem?

Comment: What happens if lhs has smaller order than rhs? Won't you exceed the bounds of lhs coeff?

Comment: Please try to reduce this to a minimum example that still demonstrates the problem.

Comment: btw it's called a "destructor" not a "deconstructor"

Comment: I'm in windows environment using visual studios 10.  It's a continuing education class, so it's not a true class environment, everyone is pretty much on their own.  I'm not familiar with valgrind or gdb.  I'm executing the program through the command prompt.  The error message I get is "Polynomial.exe has stopped working" @RyanHaining

Comment: Run it in the debugger in visual studio then

Comment: In your copy constructor, you malloc some memory for temp and then you overwrite temp with another array, thus leaking memory.

Comment: `valgrind` is a linux utility to check out of bounds errors, memory leaks, invalid read/write, etc.  If you can access a linux machine I recommend you try it there.

Comment: I have no idea how to use visual studio though. (I'm a real programmer)

Comment: So am I. I use Visual Studio and get paid for it..

Comment: @NeilKirk - You're right on the malloc statements, and that's why I lost a bunch of points, so I'm going back and replacing with variables using new.  Once I leave the function, the 'new' pointer should be released since it goes out of scope of the function, correct?  I guess I could just create an array in the function anyway.

Comment: @RyanHaining: Being knowledgeable of one of the most widely used programming tools, even if you don't use it for your own personal work, makes you a better, and even more real programmer.

Comment: I highly suggest you learn about std::vector and use it instead of dynamic arrays. In fact if you use a vector, you don't even need to provide a copy constructor or assignment operator. The default ones will work correctly.

Comment: @user2608071 No, that is wrong. Allocated memory with `new` doesn't get released until you either explicitly release it with `delete` somewhere or your program terminates, in which case the OS will free it.

Comment: @greatwolf - thanks.  I'll clean up my new and malloc statements.  I'm thinking it has to be memory related, like you and NeikKirk have said.

Comment: your `Poly::PtrReset` looks really suspicious and extremely unsafe. Calling that public method with the wrong preconditions will result in `coeff` pointing to invalid memory.

Comment: The issue isnt that you used malloc instead of new, its that you MIX the two and never reclaim ANY of your memory.. No offense intended here, especially I appreciate and recognize you want to learn and already got a grade, but the fact that it wasn't a 50 or lower shocks me.  You literally leak memory on every operation you have.

Comment: I'm not reading all of that.

Comment: @UpAndAdam - Thanks for your feedback.  I posted this program while I was in the middle of removing all of the mallocs from the program.  The program now works, so the memory leaking was definitely the issue.  The reason I didn't get more taken off was b/c of the constraints on this project.  We were given all the function defs, and basically had to fill in the code to back it up.  Thanks again for your feedback.

Comment: gotcha, understand that as well which is why i hesitated to mess with signatures immediately. I remember those days.  I do have to say it's very odd to see an assignment operator that doesn't return `*this` and that returns an object and not a reference to one. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I see this, the usual problem behind it is a double free/delete.  You're likely calling free on the same pointer twice (or an invalid pointer) which causes everything to get weird and a crash can pretty much happen at any time.

This can also happen when you mix malloc and new.  Switch everything to new and see if you still get your crash.

Comment: how is it a double free when he never free's and deletes.  while you shouldn't mix them there is nothing wrong as long as you always free what you malloc and delete what you new.  In his case he ALSO mixes new and malloc for the same members which IS a problem

Answer (score 2):

`Assignment operator` as a member should return a reference to `this`
**If it isn't going to then you probably shouldn't be using the `assignment operator`.**

Commented line aside, another immediate problem with your assignment operator is that you are leaking more memory when you manually build up a new coeff array.  You are also returning a third object which is NOT what anyone using the `assignment operator` would ever expect and this is downright DANGEROUS

```
Poly& Poly::operator=(const Poly &rhs)
{
    order = rhs.order;
    // you should probably initialize coeff here

    //cout << "new order = " << rhs.order << endl;  ******HERE*******

    for(int i(0); i <= rhs.order; i++)
        coeff[i] = rhs.coeff[i];

    //This is wrong return this. see signature fix above
    //return Poly(order, coeff);
    return *this;
```

}

Secondly instead of manually mucking about with whatever you are doing in your algebraic operators, copy construct FIRST and then modify THAT object.

for example for multiplication:

```
//member multiplication which still sucks because we are going to copy construct again to return..
Poly Poly::operator*(const int scale)
{
    Poly result(*this);
    // now manipulate your new object and leave THIS this alone

    for(int i(0); i <= result.order; i++)
        result.coeff[i] *= scale;

    return result;
}
```

Even better if you make this a non member function and then create a member function `*=operator` and then you can do as Ben and I envisioned

```
Poly operator*(Poly result, int scale)
{
    return (result *= scale);
}
```

The major issue as I see is you are wildly leaking memory and never have any bounds protection on it.

Comment: Your latter code snippet looks like an example of exactly what you told him NOT to do, as it modifies members of `this`.  Actually, a better way to write that would be `Poly operator*(Poly result, const int scale) { result *= scale; return result; }`

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks, made a typo and omitted 'result.' in there, and accidentally repasted his old stuff in while fixing something else.

I would have done that and was going to, but he doesnt have a *= eihter so i didnt want to jump there... but that's exactly what I would have done.

Comment: I didn't go in to the optimization that we should pass by reference here... and return by reference..